# Why aren't all the required tiles loaded at different zoom levels in Leaflet.js when you set the tileSize to 1024px?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tile

I would like to use tiles in a size of 1024x1024 px. When I open the map and display it in Leaflet, it does not load all the required tiles at different zoom levels.
Here is a small example:

[image: zoomlevel 0]

[image: zoomlevel 1]

[image: zoomlevel 2]

As you can see from the different zoom levels, only zoom level 0 is displayed correctly and tiles are missing at the other zoom levels.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
<head>
<title>MapViewer</title>
<meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
crossorigin=""/>
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
 crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body style = "height: 100%; margin: 0;">
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxZoomLevel = 2;
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {minZoom: 0,maxZoom: maxZoomLevel,
continuesWorld: false,
noWrap: true, 
tileSize: 1024}).addTo(map);
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: The maximum tile size is the maximum size of a HTML `<img>`. You're not asking the right question.

Comment: (1/2) Then to the concrete problem: If I set the TileSize to 1024x1024 px then a tile should have exactly this size. This means that at zoom level 0, exactly one tile of this size is displayed. If I now zoom to zoom level 1, it should load four tiles of this size(of course, depending on where I am on the map, there may be fewer).

Comment: (2/2) At this zoom level, however, a maximum of one tile is loaded no matter how I move around the map. So my question was if there is any limit on how big a tile can be. Even if the limit depends on the html <img> leaflet doesn't seem to load all the tiles needed for the map if the tile size is too big and I don't understand why and how to fix it. @IvanSanchez

Comment: Please edit your question and add all details needed to reproduce the problem. Also, if you're using L.Simple.CRS, there's infinite tiles at any zoom level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited the question. Is this enough to reproduce the problem? @IvanSanchez

Comment: You were using `L.CRS.Simple` before, now you're not. What's the right one?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. I tried a lot of things and removed the L.CRS.Simple. That didn't change the result for me. The screenshots are based on the code in the question.

Comment: It does change the behaviour. Try https://plnkr.co/edit/Yu5CjMABEkwB30Rf , comment/uncomment the `L.CRS.Simple` line.

Comment: I put the L.CRS.Simple in L.tileLayer and it made no difference. You did it directly in L.map. When I use your code it works as it should. Thank you very much for your help! @IvanSanchez